# Tips for starting in motion design

Tags: animation, character-design, character, animate

This may be the wrong place to post this type of question but here i go...

So recently i've been really interested in motion design like the examples i've put below 
[example 1](http://drbl.in/oQts/)
[example 2](http://drbl.in/oPIe/)

But i'm not too sure where to start or even begin, could you offer some insight or tips on where i should start an begin when looking at these type of animations.

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider that motion graphics, but 2D character animation.

Where to begin is not a clear question because we don't know where you currently are.

#### Drawing

- Do you know how to draw at all? (Pencil and paper)
- Do you know how to draw on a computer? (Paint, yes... paint or something similar)
- Do you know how to make a character in vectors? (Corel, Illustrator, Serif Draw, Inkscape)

#### Animation

- Do you know how to animate? (Drawing the sides of the books of the school, playing with Play Doh and a camera)
- Do you know any principles of animation?
- Do you "see" the physics related to animation? (preparation, elasticity, action-reaction)
- Do you know the difference in a drawn by hand animation and an interpolated one? *(Please guys correct if that is not the right term)*

If you know all that, then the next step is an animation program. These may be useful.

- Blender. It is a 3D program, but you can be creative and use it for 2D. (free)
- Crazy Talk Animator. https://www.reallusion.com/crazytalk/animator/
- Anime studio. http://my.smithmicro.com/anime-studio-2D-animation-software.html
- Flash. http://www.adobe.com/mx/products/flash.html
- Vectorian Giotto (free) http://vectorian.com/giotto/
- After effects. http://www.adobe.com/mx/products/aftereffects.html

There are some other programs for 2D drawn animation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that these are not motion graphics but are 2D animations and if you are at a level where you know design programs like illustrator or photoshop to create flat illustrations, I recommend to start with after effects for animations. This is a good program to learn how to work with basic animations (or more complex) and timelines.